# Why the ant on rubber rope paradox does not work in our universe or de Sitter universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

The [ant on rubber rope paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_on_a_rubber_rope) says that an ant moving along a rubber rope that can infinitely expand will reach the other end of the rope regardless of how fast the rope expands and how slow the ant moves.

Why then multiple sources say that there is cosmic event horizon, and two persons at some distance exceedidng Hubble limit would not be able to meet?

Comment: Are you sure that there are sources that state that this paradox does not apply in an expanding universe?  Because as the universe expands, the Hubble volume grows larger, and the regions of space that can communicate with one-another become progressively larger and larger.

Comment: @Buzz in de Sitter universe Hubble volume is constant.

Comment: @Buzz if the universe expands with acceleration, Hubble volume shrinks, if the universe expands with deceleration, Hubble volume grows.

Comment: The “ant on a rubber rope” problem corresponds to FLRW universe with $k=0$ and $a(t)=C~t$. There is no cosmic horizon for such a universe.

Comment: @A.V.S. so, FLRW universe has a Hubble horizon but no event horizon?

Comment: @Anixx, you are wrong in regards to the shrinking Hubble volume at accelerated expansion, a constant Hubble parameter like in De Sitter is already accelerated expansion. To quote [Davis & Lineweaver](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808): *"In accelerating universes H also tends to decrease since $\dot{a}$ increases more slowly than $a$"*. The ant only works in a decelerating universe without a cosmological constant Λ, otherwise the space expands faster than the ant can run.

Comment: @Yukterez hmmm. I was under impression that ant works regardless of the speed of expansion?

Comment: @Anixx - with constant speed as if the rubber band expands by some fixed meters by second, not with acceleration. If you travel at constant speed a light ray from behind can reach you, but if you accelerate it can't, see the Rindler horizon, which is a different pair of shoes, but you get the point.

Comment: @Yukterez hmm. Suppose we have two points $A$ and $B$ with proper speed $0$ at distance $x$ At $t=0$ the ant starts from point $A$ to point $B$. The space stars to expand with whatever speed or acceleration. Would it be wrong to say that the ant in each second increases the share of completed distance compared to the whole distance?

Comment: @Anix - it would, but it asymtotically approaches a fixed [comoving distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_and_proper_distances) at such and such % which it never quite reaches.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the ant-on-rope problem as stated in the Wikipedia article, the rope's expansion is linear. That means the ant's speed as a fraction of the rope length per unit time goes like $t^{-1}$, so the total fraction of the rope length it has traveled goes like $\log t$, which is a function that attains arbitrarily large values, but very slowly. It follows that the ant can reach the end of an arbitrarily long rope, but it may take a very long time.

If the rope's expansion is superlinear, that argument doesn't work. E.g., if it expands like $t^{1.001}$, the ant's speed goes like $t^{-1.001}$, and the integral of that goes like $-t^{-0.001}$, which approaches a maximum value as $t\to\infty$, so the ant can get stuck.

In ΛCDM cosmology, the expansion is superlinear.

Comment: Note that this is pointed out in the last paragraph of the Wikipedia article linked by the OP, with a reference to [McCartney, "Extending the rubber rope: convergent series, divergent series and the integrating factor",](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739X.2012.729615) Int. J. Math. Ed. Sci. Tech. **44** (4), 554-559 (2013).